# ATK4 Autocomplete submit form on select or Enter

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, atk4

I've got a form with an Autocomplete/Basic that works as expected (I suppose). I type three characters, get matches, etc.
When I select a match, either with keys (and confirm with Enter) or mouse click it takes another Enter to submit the form. This feels... unnatural :-)

So I'm trying to get the Autocomplete/Basic form field to submit the form for me after a selection has been made.

My first (misguided) test attempt involved doing something along the lines of:

```
$form->getElement('fieldname')->js('select', $form->js()->univ()->alert('Select!'));
```

This fires when text is selected in the form field, not quite what I was looking for.

I started looking at autocomplete_univ.js and (unsuccesfully) added $(other_field).closest('form').submit();
But I don't know jQuery/JS very well at all, so I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

Any ideas on how to trigger (a submit) on Autocomplete selection?

```
this.jquery.autocomplete($.extend({
        source: data,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            // Imants: fix for item selecting with mouse click
            var e=event;
            while(e.originalEvent!==undefined) e=e.originalEvent;
            if(e.type!='focus') q.val( ui.item[title_field] );

            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            q.val( ui.item[title_field] );
            $(other_field).val( ui.item[id_field] );
            //Added this line below
            $(other_field).closest('form').submit();

            return false;
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            var data=$.data(this);//Get plugin data for 'this'
            if(data.uiAutocomplete.selectedItem==undefined) {
                if("mustMatch" in options) q.val('');
                $(other_field).val(q.val());

                return false;
            }
        }
    },options))
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item[title_field] + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Comment: Did some more reading: 
    $(other_field).val( ui.item[id_field] ); 
when changed to 
    $(other_field).val( ui.item[id_field].val ); 
triggers the submit like I wanted. Except now the value I needed from the field is not being passed anymore.

Can anyone explain to me why and suggest a fix?

Comment: I changed back to $(other_field).val( ui.item[id_field] ); and I don't know why - but now it appears to work as expected, submitting with the id being passed as needed.
Can someone confirm that the above code works as advertised: submits the form and passes the id both with mouse selection and keypresses?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess your chane in ATKs JS library is not correct.

What probably should work is to hook to other_field onChange event.
Something like this:

```
$(other_field).change(
    function(){$(other_field).closest('form').submit();}
);
```